# Corpus to Dataframe adding numbers to data

Tags: r, tm

I'm attempting to pre-process a text file and then export it back to a new text file.  For the most part, I think I have it pretty cleaned up but noticed that numbers are being added to the dataframe.  I've checked the original file and they are not there and they seem to be the same number patterns.

```
library(tm)
aFile = readLines("C:/myfile.txt")
aFile = gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', aFile)
aFile = gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', aFile)
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(aFile))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(myCorpus))
dataframe <- data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(myCorpus, `[`)), stringsAsFactors=F)
view(dataframe)
```

I stripped out those numbers in the output with another tool but was interested in why it was included in the first place. The original file was ANSI encoded if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the row names. If you want to remove them when you write out the file you can do so using:

```
write.table(dataFrame, "fileName.tbl", row.names = FALSE)
```

or with the same argument in write.csv. When you set rownames(dataFrame) = NULL, when you print the data.frame, it just prints numbers.

Comment: I tried the row.names = False and it still put them in there.  The odd thing is that it basically lists the first row (what I want).  The next 10 lines are numbers followed by a "en" line.  The second row follows that.  The odd thing is that this group of numbers and 'en' is the same numbers and always falls between each row that I'm looking to post.